# Strange errors running built-in methods on pandas index objects

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, pandas

I'm trying to extract the column name that corresponds to the max value in a particular row of a data frame. Here's my general strategy:

```
best_MAP = df.ix['map',].max()  # Identify the value
ix = df.ix['map',] == best_MAP  # build a boolean vector to select the element corresponding to this value
best_param = df.columns[ix] # pull that element out
```

(I'm presenting this all here in case there's a better way to do this)

The result, `best_param` is a pandas `Index` object. For the purpose of creating a reproducible example, this case throws the error I describe below:

```
best_param = pd.core.index.Index([.19, .20])
```

If there is a unique max value in the row, then this index is only one element and I can extract the `float64` I need via

```
best_param[0]
```

But I've encountered cases where there are multiple records in the `'map'` row with the same value (the max). I noticed that the Index object (containing the corresponding column identifiers) has both a `.min()` and a `.max()` method, so I thought this might be a good way to extract a single value. Any of the following throws a repeating error in Ipython that finally exits with a "recursion limit reached" catch:

```
best_param.min()
best_param.max()
np.min(best_param)
np.max(best_param)
```

Here's an excerpt of the crazy error I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in as_esca
ped_unicode(thing, escape_chars)
   2026
   2027         try:
-> 2028             result = unicode(thing)  # we should try this first
   2029         except UnicodeDecodeError:
   2030             # either utf-8 or we replace errors

C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in __unicod
e__(self)
    149         Invoked by unicode(df) in py2 only. Yields a Unicode String in b
oth py2/py3.
    150         """
--> 151         prepr = com.pprint_thing(self, escape_chars=('\t', '\r', '\n'),q
uote_strings=True)
    152         return '%s(%s, dtype=%s)' % (type(self).__name__, prepr, self.dt
ype)
    153

C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in pprint_
thing(thing, _nest_lvl, escape_chars, default_escapes, quote_strings)
   2065         result = fmt % as_escaped_unicode(thing)
   2066     else:
-> 2067         result = as_escaped_unicode(thing)
   2068
   2069     return unicode(result)  # always unicode

C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in as_esca
ped_unicode(thing, escape_chars)
   2026
   2027         try:
-> 2028             result = unicode(thing)  # we should try this first
   2029         except UnicodeDecodeError:
   2030             # either utf-8 or we replace errors

C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in __unicod
e__(self)
    149         Invoked by unicode(df) in py2 only. Yields a Unicode String in b
oth py2/py3.
    150         """
--> 151         prepr = com.pprint_thing(self, escape_chars=('\t', '\r', '\n'),q
uote_strings=True)
    152         return '%s(%s, dtype=%s)' % (type(self).__name__, prepr, self.dt
ype)
    153

C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in pprint_
thing(thing, _nest_lvl, escape_chars, default_escapes, quote_strings)
   2065         result = fmt % as_escaped_unicode(thing)
   2066     else:
-> 2067         result = as_escaped_unicode(thing)
   2068
   2069     return unicode(result)  # always unicode

C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in as_esca
ped_unicode(thing, escape_chars)
   2026
   2027         try:
-> 2028             result = unicode(thing)  # we should try this first
   2029         except UnicodeDecodeError:
   2030             # either utf-8 or we replace errors

C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in __unicod
e__(self)
    149         Invoked by unicode(df) in py2 only. Yields a Unicode String in b
oth py2/py3.
    150         """
--> 151         prepr = com.pprint_thing(self, escape_chars=('\t', '\r', '\n'),q
uote_strings=True)
    152         return '%s(%s, dtype=%s)' % (type(self).__name__, prepr, self.dt
ype)
    153

C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in pprint_
thing(thing, _nest_lvl, escape_chars, default_escapes, quote_strings)
   2051             hasattr(thing, 'next'):
   2052         return unicode(thing)
-> 2053     elif (isinstance(thing, dict) and
   2054           _nest_lvl < get_option("display.pprint_nest_depth")):
   2055         result = _pprint_dict(thing, _nest_lvl,quote_strings=True)

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
```

What the hell is going on here? I'm guessing this is a bug in pandas, but historically whenever I blame my tools I've found it's usually me and not the tool that's the problem. Does it maybe have something to do with using non-integer numerics for column IDs?

This is using the Anaconda distribution in an Ipython console with the following software versions:

- Pandas 0.12.0
- Numpy 1.7.1
- Ipython 2.7.5
- Anaconda 1.8.0

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with 0.13.

Comment: Do you mean: `best_param = df.index[ix]` ?

Comment: was a bug in < 0.13.1 (though sometimes does work depending in the index type)

Comment: @AndyHayden No, I don't. The columns each correspond to a test of a different parameter value (and are named with the parameter value), and the rows are different metrics. I'm trying to extract that parameter that gave the highest metric. So I need `df.columns[ix]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is to take the max/min from the numpy values:

```
In [11]: ind = pd.Index([.19, .20])

In [21]: ind.values.max()
Out[21]: 0.2
```

*This was a bug (present in 0.13.1) but [fixed in master](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6449)...*

Comment: better 2 reset the index and do the computation

Comment: yeh, confused what the game plan is here.